# Injecting EJB3 / CDI / JSF beans in console application for testing / experimentation purposes

Tags: java, jsf, ejb, cdi

Is there any way to inject EJB3 / CDI / JSF beans (if the last category makes any sense) and use the respective annotations without having to use a Java EE container? I.e. in a plain old **static void main** type console application?

Reason might be for experimentation / testing / behavior deciphering purposes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EJB3, CID and JSF runs over a Java EE container: [GlassFish](http://glassfish.java.net/), [JBoss](http://www.jboss.org/as7), [IBM WebSphere Application Server](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/webservers/appserv/was/) and so on. Note that [Tomcat](http://tomcat.apache.org/) is not a Java EE container, it's a Servlet/JSP container.

A console project, in the other hand, run over Java SE container, this is, a simple JRE installation. If you try to download the [Java Platform, Enterprise Edition 6 SDK](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javaee/downloads/java-ee-sdk-6u3-web-downloads-439820.html), you will notice that it's a GlassFish distribution.

If you want/need to do proof of concepts using these technologies, you should create a simple Web project and deploy it on any Java EE containers. IMO I would recommend JBoss AS 7 for being lightweight on deployment (note: people can correct me if I'm wrong).

Comment: EJB and JSF will not run in an SE environment for sure, however, both Weld and Open WebBeans run in SE. For testing, yes you'll need to use a container. JBoss AS7 is great as is TomEE also take a look at Arquillian.

Comment: @LightGuard I've just check on Arquillian and looks promising for EJB testing. Good catch on that!

Comment: @LightGuard Note that the Embedded EJB Container API added to EJB 3.1 is for running EJB in Java SE

Comment: @David you're correct. I'd forgotten about the embedded container :) However, JSF still has problems running outside of EE land.